# adding pre- and post- actions around an existing windows program?

Tags: windows-xp, batch, automation, script

There is a program I use all day long and it's data resides in a single, large file.

I work at 2 different locations and sometimes also on the road and need current data.

In the best of days I remember to copy the file to my USB stick and an FTP location; but too often I get busy and forget.

I have been searching for some time now to do in XP what used to be fairly easy in DOS with a simple batch file to automate this process:

1. Call a pre-defined sync job to make sure the newest file is on hand
2. Once that is assured, open the program
3. When the program closes, re-sync the data file with the latest version on hand.

I hope I've described this well enough !!!

It seems to just be 3 simple steps, but finding a really good method or tool to do this has perplexed me despite searching many times.

Thanks.

Comment: My query brings to mind that I've tried to use Autoit for a couple of other things before, but was not very good at it. This set of actions may be possible with that, but I have little faith in my ability to make it happen without a very long learning time.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution, depending on certain specific elements, is to use Remote Desktop or VNC to alter how you work slightly, so that you are always actually, only working on one computer.  If you have an internet connection when you are on the road, you can just RDP/VNC into your computer at the other location, and use the program on THAT machine.  Therefore only ever accessing one source of Data.

You could also use a third party Sync program like [Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/quotes.html).

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I live & work in a very rural area and cannot depend upon having reliable connections - also the data file is around 50 MB in size. I already have a very good sync program, thanks - it is my own memory which I cannot dpend upon !!!

Answer (score 0):

The sort of script you are asking about is commonly written using Microsoft PowerShell. You can find lots of information and tutorials to get you started at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/default

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look there and hope I can easily learn how to do this !?!